# Display All List Property in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display my list. But my list is a constructor and I want only one property to display.

This is my CardClass:

```
class CardClass {
  int deger;
  String tip;
  int id;
  String image;

  CardClass(this.deger, this.tip, this.id, this.image);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ ${deger}, ${tip}}';
  }
}
```

This is my CardBrain class:

```
class CardBrain {
  List<CardClass> cardbank = [
    CardClass(1, "maca", 1, "images/AS.png"),
    CardClass(2, "maca", 2, "images/2S.png"),
    CardClass(3, "maca", 3, "images/3S.png"),
   ];
}
```

I want to show all images (Only images).

My code is like this but it shows only last elements image:

```
cardChild: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('${cardBrain.mycards.last.image}'),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a ListView.builder or GridView.builder for showing all images:

```
cardChild: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: cardBrain.mycards.lenght;
  itemBuilder: (context, i) => Image(
     image: AssetImage('${cardBrain.mycards[i].image}'),
  ),
),
```

Comment: itemCount : cardBrain.mycards.lenght ==> is doesn't work. It says : " The getter lenght isnt defined for the type List<CardClass> "

Comment: You should enter the lenght of list that you get image from instead of that